# Buildfire - Is there a way to direct people to another tab within the admin dashboard?

Tags: buildfire

In my admin dashboard I have a custom tab that is used for displaying access requests made by users within the widget.  I give the admin some options in this custom tab.  One of these options is to grant the request.  When the admin grants the requests however, they must then assign the user that requested access to a plugin so they can be redirected in the future.

I have this functionality set up in another tab and don't really want to replicate it in this custom tab if I don't have to.  Is there anyway to, on clicking of the grant access button, send the admin to the other tab with some data from previous tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately There is no navigate to Tab feature. However you can actually navigate to other page directly which will take you there under the same tab (not ideal but will get the job done)

Or a much cleaner solution would be building a SPA architecture like the People or Places plugin with virtual tabs and breadcrumbs
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-Breadcrumbs

ref:

- https://github.com/BuildFire/peoplePlugin
- https://github.com/BuildFire/placesPlugin

Hope this helps